# Enumerate based on session number

Tags: enumerate

I want to use enumerate to number a text as:

```
\begin{enumerate}
    3.1
    3.2
    3.3
    3.4
\end{enumerate}

\begin{enumerate}
    4.1
    4.2
    4.3
\end{enumerate}
```

Thank you.

Comment: I'm afraid your objective is not entirely clear. For instance, what is a "session number"?

Comment: Do you mean *section number*?

Comment: Could you add a [mininal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that) showing how you intend to use this. I'll help us to answer your request.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not totally sure that I understood your question correctly, but I think the following should fit your needs.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\newcounter{session}
\newlist{myenumerate}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[myenumerate]{%
    label=\arabic{session}.\arabic{*},
    before=\stepcounter{session}
}

\begin{document}

First enumeration:
\begin{myenumerate}
    \item
    \item
    \item
    \item
\end{myenumerate}

Second enumeration:
\begin{myenumerate}
    \item
    \item
    \item
\end{myenumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]